# Descarga de imagenes NDVI, EVI y GCI con Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm new to using Google Earth Engine and I find it a little confusing. I need to download images of three Landsat 5 and 8 spectral indices of an area in Paraguay. I use the GEE base script but then I get lost when it comes to downloading.

Comment: Sarahí, vuelve a preguntar en Ingles, además adjunta el código que has desarrollado hasta el momento